# nopCommerce: Plugin needs configuraton tab/page for each product

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am developing a plugin for nopCommerce for a client of mine. It will show extra details for each product on the UI. I have it working so far, but now I need to add a way to edit this information per product from the admin page... I was thinking of a separate tab page for it. How would I go about this?

I followed this example for the plugin:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx

But there's nothing in there about setting up a widget or whatever in the admin pages to edit the new info for each product. Any ideas / examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me get what I needed: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/18721/admintabstribcreated.aspx

Basically, you need to add an `IConsumer<AdminTabStripCreated>` and in the `HandleEvent` method, you can add a new tab.